Animated TV show with a boy who was chosen to bond to a fire element partner and competed with other people
I'm trying to indentify an animated TV show which I saw somewhere around 2018-2019. It was 3D and had a pretty distinct style.
I think the main character had black hair, and he really dreamt of having a partner. The partners look like mini robots and are fully capable of talking. He got bonded/chosen in a store of some sort to a fire element partner.
His enemy for part of the show had really blond hair and a yellow partner which I think is metal or gold attributed.
There are also attributed disks that are put into a slot on the partner and summons the being on the disk.
This was really long ago, so I don’t remember the details too well.

In roughly which year/s did you watch this? Also, was the animation 2D (hand-drawn) or 3D (computer-generated)?

Somewhere around 2018-2019. It was 3D and had a pretty distinct style.

This sounds like it could be Battle Disc? There's not a lot of info on it, but according to IMDB and the Amazon Prime listing:

Disc Warriors (small robots) need to find partners to participate in the tournament.

The tournament involves "Beast Discs"

The MC's Disc Warrior is named Blaze, is red, and looks fire-themed. He was teleported to Earth to find a partner.

MC - "Ken is a boy who loves battle disc, but isn't very experienced in it and he doesn't have many friends." This fits with "he really dreamt of having a partner".

The MC has blue hair, not black, but it's darkish.

One of the episodes mentions the MC fighting "Gordon", and the thumbnail is someone with yellow hair (or a yellow helmet?) with a yellow Disc Warrior.


